# Does Xamarin support COM?

Tags: com, mono, xamarin

Does the MonoProject or Xamarin studio support Microsoft's COM technology? Was wondering if I could use the ole32.dll in mono. I can already use some dll's for .net, but I get a not found exception when using others that rely on ole32.dll.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/COM_Interop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

> Mono 1.0 and Mono 1.1.xx do not have support for COM, it is a known
>   missing feature of Mono. Initial work has begun on supporting MS COM
>   on Windows. The long term goal is to support a variety of unmanaged
>   component technologies including MS COM, XPCOM, and UNO.