# Xamarin.Mac Unified API and System.Windows.Forms

Tags: xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

I recently upgraded to the Xamarin.Mac Unified API.  Before the upgrade I was using a `FolderBrowserDialog` by means of `System.Windows.Forms`.   By upgrading I no longer have access to the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.  I contacted customer support and they suggested referencing the native APIs.  So I added this [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-ShellExtensions/) with its dependencies.  The presence of that nuget took away the intellisense errors for the following code:

```
   var dir = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures.ToString ();

   var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog ();
   dlg.Title = "Exclude Subdirectories";
   dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
   dlg.InitialDirectory = dir;
   dlg.AddToMostRecentlyUsedList = false;
   dlg.AllowNonFileSystemItems = false;
   dlg.DefaultDirectory = dir;
   dlg.EnsureFileExists = true;
   dlg.EnsurePathExists = true;
   dlg.EnsureReadOnly = false;
   dlg.EnsureValidNames = true;
   dlg.Multiselect = false;
   dlg.ShowPlacesList = true;

   if (dlg.ShowDialog () == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok) {
      var folder = dlg.FileName;
   }
```

But at runtime it busts citing a `System.DllNotFoundException` for **ole32.dll**.  Any ideas of how to overcome this?  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578437/does-xamarin-support-com) doesn't make it sound hopeful.  My only option at this point is to revert back to the classic api...and if I do that I don't believe it can ever be put in the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for that nuget at all.  You can accomplish a FolderBrowserDialog with this code:

```
NSOpenPanel openDlg = NSOpenPanel.OpenPanel;
openDlg.Prompt = "Select Directory"; //Defaults to OPEN
openDlg.CanChooseDirectories = true;
openDlg.CanChooseFiles = false;
openDlg.Title = "Choose Monitored Directory";
openDlg.AllowsMultipleSelection = false;
openDlg.CanCreateDirectories = true;
openDlg.ReleasedWhenClosed = true;

openDlg.DirectoryUrl = new NSUrl (Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
openDlg.Begin (result => {
    var url = openDlg.Url;

    if (result == 1) {
        //directory selected
    } else {
        //cancelled
    }
});
```